# Как можно укоротить код?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используя   цикл while найти   максимальное   значений   функции y(смотрите скрин)
для ∈[−5;12] с  шагом  изменения xравным  0,9  среди полученных значений функции, в которых она определена. Значение параметра b вводиться с клавиатуры.

```
import math
b=int(input('Введите значение b - '))
x=-5
dx=0.9
max_=(math.tan(b*x**(4-x)+2*x)+3*x)/(math.sqrt((b*x-3)**2)-3*x**3)
while x<=12:
    if math.sqrt((b*x-3)**2)-3*x**3!=0:
        if (4-x)%2==0:
            y=(math.tan(b*x**(4-x)+2*x)+3*x)/(math.sqrt((b*x-3)**2)-3*x**3)
            if y>max_:
                max_=y
    x+=dx
print(max_)
```

Comment: По-моему его наоборот стоит удлиннить... Вынести повторяющиеся формулы в отдельные функции хотя бы что ли

Comment: @andreymal а что удлиннять? вроде работает

Comment: andreymal покажите мастер класс.

Comment: Я думаю, что можно только ускорить с помощью библиотеки numpy, так как она вычислит все значения из заданного интервала одновременно.

Comment: @СергейКох *Используя цикл while*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подход как укоротить и немного ускорить код за счет:

- обработки ошибок;
- исключения из формулы корня из квадрата (взаимно исключаются);
- исключения инициирования `max_` результатом вычисления до цикла.

Добавил немного отладочной информации.

```
import math

b = int(input('Введите значение b - '))
x, dx, max_ = -5, 0.9, None
while x <= 12:
    try:
        y = (math.tan(b * x ** (4 - x) + 2 * x) + 3 * x) / (b * x - 3 - 3 * x ** 3)
        if (max_ is None) or y > max_[1]:
            max_ = (x, y)
    except:
        print(f'Функция не определена при x = {x:.02f}')
    x += dx
print(f'Максимальное значение функции = {max_[1]:.04f} при х = {max_[0]:.04f}')
```

```
Введите значение b - 15
Функция не определена при x = -4.10
Функция не определена при x = -3.20
Функция не определена при x = -2.30
Функция не определена при x = -1.40
Функция не определена при x = -0.50
Максимальное значение функции = 2.0442 при х = 0.4000
```

Примечание. Исходный код в цикле вычисляет функцию только при x = 4.0, обратите внимание, скорее всего проверка `if (4-x)%2==0:` не вполне корректна.